# Android Studio - Can't change theme using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, themes

So, I cannot for the life of me figure out **why** this code will not work as expected. I have a theory, that it is my AndroidManifest having the "android:theme" defined by default, but I can't be certain. Code show below.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.advancedshoppinglist">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AdvancedShoppingList.Light">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:titleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

SettingsFragment.kt

```
package com.example.advancedshoppinglist

import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.preference.ListPreference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
        Log.d("Code Changed", "Something happend");
        val preference = findPreference<ListPreference>(key)
        if (preference != null && key == "theme") {
            // Handle changes to your ListPreference here
            val selectedValue = preference.value
            // Do something with the selected value
            Log.d("PREFERENCE CHANGED", "It changed to " + selectedValue)
            when(selectedValue) {
                "light" -> requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Light)
                "dark" -> requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Dark)
            }

            requireActivity().recreate()
        }
    }

}
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AdvancedShoppingList.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AdvancedShoppingList.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now, I know that the **onSharedPreferenceChanged** is being triggered inside **SettingsFragement.kt** because I can see it in the logs. The "Emulator" closes and re-opens the app after selecting a new theme as well (which I think it is meant to do?)

But still, the following element is **not changing** based on the theme preference...

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:titleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
```

After many, many attempts and using ChatGPT for assistance, nothing has yet worked. Tried removing the "app:theme" from AndroidManifest.xml, it just broke. Also tried...

```
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Light) // or Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Dark
```

In the onCreate function inside MainActivity.kt and nothing. I am completely lost.

Comment: You explicitly set the background of your toolbar to white, which will override whatever is in either theme. Or do you mean you are expecting the text color in the toolbar to change between purple and black?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the reply. Yeah, it is the text colour that is not changing from "Purple" (in the light theme) to "Black" (in the dark theme) and vice versa

Comment: The rest of the colors on the screen change? It could be a peculiarity of Toolbar specifically, like trying to ensure contrast between background and text colors.

Comment: Hey, @Tenfour04 at the moment I have no colour switch of the toolbar, only the text of it. I can try that later on to see if that changes.

Comment: You should be seeing the whole screen changing color because the dark theme has a very dark gray background and the light theme has a white background by default.

Comment: @Tenfour04 No joy, I am afraid. Even adding ?attr/colorPrimary to the background colour of the Toolbar, the theme switch doesn't work.

Comment: Stab in the dark. try adding an else branch to that when statement and logging to see if maybe it's not "light" or "dark" for some reason.

Comment: @Tenfour04 No luck, I'm afraid. Added the following...

            when(selectedValue) {
                "light" -> {
                    Log.d("CHANGED_THEME", "LIGHT")
                    requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Light)
                }
                "dark" -> {
                    Log.d("CHANGED_THEME", "DARK")
                    requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Dark)
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d("PROBLEM", "Value not detected")
                }
            }

Comment: Sorry about that, thought I could add code to comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, here is what I have and it finally works. However, I have a few questions at the end of the code.

**SettingsFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.advancedshoppinglist

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.preference.ListPreference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Load the preferences from the XML resource
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, null)

        // Set the initial theme based on the saved preference value
        val selectedValue = findPreference<ListPreference>("theme")?.value
        setAppTheme(selectedValue)
    }

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
        val preference = findPreference<ListPreference>(key)
        if (preference != null && key == "theme") {
            val selectedValue = preference.value // Get the new theme preference value

            val sharedPrefs = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("root_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = sharedPrefs.edit()

            editor.putString("theme", selectedValue) // Save the new theme preference
            editor.apply()

            // Handle changes to your ListPreference here
            Log.d("PREFERENCE CHANGED", "It changed to $selectedValue")
            setAppTheme(selectedValue)
            requireActivity().recreate()
        }
    }

    private fun setAppTheme(selectedValue: String?) {
        when (selectedValue) {
            "light" -> requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Light)
            "dark" -> requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Dark)
            else -> requireActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Light) // Default theme
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.advancedshoppinglist

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Load the saved theme preference from SharedPreferences
        val preferences = getSharedPreferences("root_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedTheme = preferences.getString("theme", "light") // Default to "Light" if not found

        // Apply the appropriate theme based on the saved preference
        when (savedTheme) {
            "light" -> setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Light)
            "dark" -> setTheme(R.style.Theme_AdvancedShoppingList_Dark)
            // Add more cases for other custom themes if needed
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    }

    /**
     * Create the options menu within the AppBar
     *
     * @return Boolean
     */
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the options menu button clicks
     *
 

* @return void
 */
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            val fragment = SettingsFragment();
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit()
            true
        }
        R.id.action_support -> {
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

}

Questions...

1. Is there not a way to set the theme globally from SettingsFragment alone, or do I always need to set the theme based on the preference within MainActivity.kt? If so, why?
2. I noticed that I had to manually save the theme preference in order to get the value of it to use within onCreate inside MainActivity.kt. However, why do I need to do this? Why is it that the "preference" is saved and displays correctly (even after rebooting emulator) within SettingsFragement.kt but MainActivity.kt (before manually saving) did not know the value of it?

I am very, very new to Android Studio/Kotlin (by like a few days) so my brain hurts and I can't make very good heads or tails of why it does what it does.